# UITableView allowsSelection property for specific section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

is there a way to set the **allowsSelection** property of UITableView for each table section separately, and not for the whole table ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. Here's what you do: use the indexPath.section value to set the cell's `.selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` and to return early from `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

In other words, you'll configure cells in certain sectinos to not flash blue when selected, and when it IS selected, not to do anything. It'll be just as if that section had its `allowsSelection` property set to NO.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [willSelectRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method and return nil for the section you don't want to allow selection on.

Comment: Setting `selectionStyle` to None and return nil in `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will do the trick.